# (Angular) ng-deep to change specific elements

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

If anyone knows how to change specific elements with ng-deep.

I want to change the color of placeholder from Grey to White.

〇HTML

`<md-input-container class="header-inputContainer">
    <input class="header-inputBar" mdInput placeholder="荷主">
  </md-input-container>`

〇CSS

`::ng-deep .mat-input-placeholder {color: #fff;}`

from this

[image]

to this.

[image]

but CSS affects other element's placeholder like this.

・element in other component(without CSS above)
[image]

・element in other component(with CSS above)

[image]

adding class name in CSS doesn't work.
If anyone could help out, that be much appreciated.

Comment: ng deep is being deprecated, may want to reconsider before using it. 

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to give it a class name, and then refer to it in your global styling (style.css).

```
.header-inputBar.mat-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but it works only without '.header-inputBar'. not effective with '.header-inputBar'....

Comment: Ah my bad! Should `.header-inputBar.mat-input-placeholder`, without space